# Enhanced Ecommerce dataLayer WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, google-tag-manager, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to set up a dataLayer for WooCommerce Thank you page. Look here what I've done so far (the variables are not completely set up yet):

```
function dataLayer_google_gtm( $order_id ) {

    // Lets grab the order
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Products
    $products = $order->get_items();
    ?>

    <script>
        dataLayer.push({
        'ecommerce': {
            'purchase': {
                'actionField':{
                    'id':'<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>',
                    'affiliation':'CHACAFOODS', 
                    'revenue':'<?php echo $order->get_order_total(); ?>',
                    'tax':'<?php echo $order->get_total_tax(); ?>',
                    'shipping':'<?php echo $order->get_shipping(); ?>',
                    'coupon':'<?php echo $order->get_order_discount_total(); ?>',
                },
                window['service'].push('products':,[
                <?php
                    $count = 0;
                    foreach( $products as $item_id => $item ) {
                        $count++;
                        $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item ); ?>
                        {
                            'name':<?php echo $item['name']; ?>',
                            'id':
                            'price': '<?php echo $order->get_line_subtotal( $item ); ?>',
                            'brand':
                            'category':
                            'variant':
                            'quantity': '<?php echo $item['qty']; ?>'
                        }
                <?php if ( count( $order->get_items() ) > $count ) { echo ","; } ?>
                <?php } ?>
                ]);
            }
        }
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'prefix_service_conversion_tracking' );
```

Can anybody tell me if my structure above will look like the enhanced ecommerce structure below in result?

google dataLayer structure:

```
<script>
// Send transaction data with a pageview if available
// when the page loads. Otherwise, use an event when the transaction
// data becomes available.
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': 'T12345',                         // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
        'affiliation': 'Online Store',
        'revenue': '35.43',                     // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
        'tax':'4.90',
        'shipping': '5.99',
        'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
      },
      'products': [{                            // List of productFieldObjects.
        'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',     // Name or ID is required.
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '15.25',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Gray',
        'quantity': 1,
        'coupon': ''                            // Optional fields may be omitted or set to empty string.
       },
       {
        'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
        'id': '67890',
        'price': '33.75',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Black',
        'quantity': 1
       }]
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Best regards, 
Anton

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<script>
      dataLayer.push({
          'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': '<?php echo $order->get_order_currency(); ?>',
            'purchase': {
              'actionField':{
                'id': '<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>',
                'affiliation': 'WooCommerce',
                'revenue': <?php echo number_format($order->get_subtotal(), 2, ".", ""); ?>,
                'tax': <?php echo number_format($order->get_total_tax(), 2, ".", ""); ?>,
                'shipping': <?php echo number_format($order->calculate_shipping(), 2, ".", ""); ?>,
                <?php if($order->get_used_coupons()): ?>
                    'coupon': '<?php echo implode("-", $order->get_used_coupons()); ?>'
                <?php endif; ?>
              },
              'products': [
                  <?php
                    foreach($order->get_items() as $key => $item):
                      $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );
                      $variant_name = ($item['variation_id']) ? wc_get_product($item['variation_id']) : '';
                  ?>
                      {
                        'name': '<?php echo $item['name']; ?>',
                        'id': '<?php echo $item['product_id']; ?>',
                        'price': '<?php echo number_format($order->get_line_subtotal($item), 2, ".", ""); ?>',
                        'brand': '',
                        'category': '<?php echo strip_tags($product->get_categories(', ', '', '')); ?>',
                        'variant': '<?php echo ($variant_name) ? implode("-", $variant_name->get_variation_attributes()) : ''; ?>',
                        'quantity': <?php echo $item['qty']; ?>
                      },
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                ]
            }
          }
      });
    </script>
```

For Brand you could use a product attribute that you then print.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot @webizon. Didn't expect an answer on this topic :)

Comment: You're welcome! This is actually the first post that I write. I'd be very happy if you'd accept the answer if you're happy with it to score me some points. Cheers!

Comment: @webizon I understand that you also have to create a `Custom Event` trigger with the value of the event as "..." according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816513/datalayer-google-tag-manager

In this case, taking you code as an example, what should be the value of the event?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained that further. So if you have this piece of code before GTM is loaded the Data Layer will be populated with these values once GTM has loaded, which means your general Google Analytics tag will pick it up if it is configured to load Enhanced Ecommerce and to take the data from the Data Layer. If you want, and this might be easier for future purposes as well and is usually how I do it, you add an event that you call for example purchase. Then you set up a trigger for that event. You put the event on the same level as the ecommerce object, right before it for example.